# Como atualizar anúncios do adsense sem atualizar a página,Double Click?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um site com anúncios do adsense, Queria que atualizar em x segundos, eu Criei uma conta no double click, fiz um novo bloco de anúncio, peguei o código de exemplo, mas na parte de googletag.defineSlot, não sei onde acho essa numeração para colocar no código.

Comment: Ficaria muito mais facil ajudar se você colaborasse postando junto a pergunta o codigo.

Comment: ok tem como mudar